# login to [sap] cloud foundry and get api response using nodejs wrapper

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on, node-modules, sap-cloud-foundry

I have a scenario, where I am trying to fetch the API responses of the following host URL of my account spaces and orgs in SAP Cloud Foundry.

```
https://api.cf.eu10.hana.ondemand.com
```

I am using nodejs (wrapper cf-client) script to authenticate but whenever I try to login it provides below error

> Error: {"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"User authentication failed: INVALID_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_LENGTH"}"}

Here is my nodejs script

```
    "use-strict";
    const endpoint = "https://api.cf.eu10.hana.ondemand.com";
    const username = "myusername"; //I have created a trial account
    const password = "Password";  //I have created a trial account
    const JsonFind = require('json-find');
    const fs = require('fs')
    const util = require('util');
    const dJSON = require('dirty-json');
    const CloudController = new (require("cf-client")).CloudController(endpoint);
    const UsersUAA = new (require("cf-client")).UsersUAA;
    const Apps = new (require("cf-client")).Apps(endpoint);
    const Spaces = new (require("cf-client")).Spaces(endpoint);
    const Orgs = new (require("cf-client")).Organizations(endpoint);
    CloudController.getInfo().then( (result) => {
        UsersUAA.setEndPoint(result.authorization_endpoint);
        return UsersUAA.login(username, password);
    }).then( (result) => {
        Orgs.setToken(result);
        return Orgs.getOrganizations();
    }).then((result) => {
        all_orgs =  result.resources //returns api
     get_orgs=util.inspect(all_orgs, {depth: null});
     console.log(get_orgs)
});
```

What I have seen is when I normally login with cf client it requires sso passcode along with username password.

How can I provide that here or any idea how can I login here and fetch the data?

Answer (score 0):

Since I did little more research on this and found out that a token generator can be used to overcome this, below code.

```
"use-strict";
    var totp = require('totp-generator');
    const endpoint = "https://api.cf.eu10.hana.ondemand.com";
    var token = totp('clientsecretidgoeshere');
    const username = "myusername"; //I have created a trial account
    const password = "Password"+token;  //I have created a trial account
    const JsonFind = require('json-find');
    const fs = require('fs')
    const util = require('util');
    const dJSON = require('dirty-json');
    const CloudController = new (require("cf-client")).CloudController(endpoint);
    const UsersUAA = new (require("cf-client")).UsersUAA;
    const Apps = new (require("cf-client")).Apps(endpoint);
    const Spaces = new (require("cf-client")).Spaces(endpoint);
    const Orgs = new (require("cf-client")).Organizations(endpoint);
    CloudController.getInfo().then( (result) => {
        UsersUAA.setEndPoint(result.authorization_endpoint);
        return UsersUAA.login(username, password);
    }).then( (result) => {
        Orgs.setToken(result);
        return Orgs.getOrganizations();
    }).then((result) => {
        all_orgs =  result.resources //returns api
     get_orgs=util.inspect(all_orgs, {depth: null});
     console.log(get_orgs)
});
```